# android - How to make transfer app via Bluetooth

Tags: android

I've seen this in some apps ,when I press send app via it shows me some options like Bluetooth and when I select Bluetooth it sends app to another device .

It sends the apk file so other users are able to install it . How can I make something like this ? How does it send the apk file ?

Comment: Do you want to know how to send data over bluetooth or how to send APK?

Comment: @prince , I was wondering how to send the apk file

Comment: So you know how to send a file over bluetooth?

Answer (score 0):

I hope that it will help:

```
// Get current ApplicationInfo to find .apk path
ApplicationInfo app = getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo();
String filePath = app.sourceDir;

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

// MIME of .apk is "application/vnd.android.package-archive".
// but Bluetooth does not accept this. Let's use "*/*" instead.
intent.setType("*/*");

// Only use Bluetooth to send .apk
intent.setPackage("com.android.bluetooth");

// Append file and send Intent
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share app"));
```